# Visual Studio 2017 KernelBase.dll Module not found exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, runtime-error, 32-bit, runtimeexception

I am trying to build a 32-bit application on Windows 10 using Visual Studios 2017. The application builds and runs fine in 64-bit, but it does not run properly from a 32-bit build.

Call Stack:

```
    KernelBase.dll!741b08b2()   Unknown Non-user code. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]        Annotated Frame
    common32.dll!77765569() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    common32.dll!77765424() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    [External Code]     Annotated Frame
>   MobileDOAS.exe!ATL::CSimpleStringT<char,0>::CSimpleStringT<char,0>(ATL::IAtlStringMgr * pStringMgr) Line 208    C++ Symbols loaded.
    common32.dll!7776649b() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    common32.dll!7776625b() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    OmniDriver32.dll!778b044e() Unknown No symbols loaded.
    MobileDOAS.exe!CSpectrometer::CSpectrometer() Line 33   C++ Symbols loaded.
    MobileDOAS.exe!CMeasurement_Traverse::CMeasurement_Traverse() Line 7    C++ Symbols loaded.
```

Debug output:

```
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Diana\git\MobileDOAS\Debug\MobileDOAS.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ocean Optics\OmniDriver\OOI_HOME\common32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Ocean Optics\OmniDriver\OOI_HOME\OmniDriver32.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msimg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.16299.192_none_d02ca7595f31d9e4\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winspool.drv'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oledlg.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\IPHLPAPI.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.16299.192_none_8e60f76b0273650f\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.16299.192_none_5d760485a7e0eb41\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'MobileDOAS.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'
Exception thrown at 0x741B08B2 (KernelBase.dll) in MobileDOAS.exe: 0xC06D007E: Module not found (parameters: 0x00DADF0C).
Unhandled exception at 0x741B08B2 (KernelBase.dll) in MobileDOAS.exe: 0xC06D007E: Module not found (parameters: 0x00DADF0C).
```

Screenshot:

[Screenshot of exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9A81.png)

I've checked the project properties for external dependencies and ensured I am using 32-bit versions for include directories. I had it working at one point but after some changes I can no longer get it to work despite trying to revert any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the 32-bit driver for the spectrometer that the code wanted to access was getting overridden by a 64-bit version automatically. After disabling automatic driver updates, removing any copies of 64-bit driver installer on my PC, and reinstalling 32-bit driver; I finally got it working.